# Can't pass Subject as parameter Vue

Tags: vue.js, rxjs

I have the following per the instructions...

```
<template>
    <jg-header :greeting="greeting" :subject="message$"></jg-header>
</template>
<script>
   import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
   const messageObservable = new Rx.Subject();
   export default{
   subscriptions: {
         message$: messageObservable
   },
   data: function(){
       return {
           greeting: "My Name"
       }
   },
</script>

<template lang="pug">
div(class="jg-header")

  md-button.md-icon-button(@click="toggle()")
      md-icon menu
  h1 {{ greeting }}
  h2 {{ subject }}
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['greeting', 'subject'],
    methods: {
        toggle: function(){
            console.log(Object.entries(this.$props)[0]);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Greeting is passed fine but subject is undefined.

> (2) ["subject", undefined]

So subject is still undefined. Why is this shouldn't it be set by the `:subject="message$"`?

Comment: It looks like you are confused about the purpose of rxjs as there is no data in the Subject.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to create a subject in a parent component then share it between two child components so one can publish and one can subscribe.

Comment: Ok, it is a little clearer. `message$` is a subscription to the observable (generally used on the template), so to do what you want you should pass `messageObservable` instead.

Comment: You don't really need VueRx for that - just the base rxjs library.

Comment: That was kinda what I was thinking now but at first I thought it helped manage observable creation.

Answer (score 0):

In vue.js, **data binding** likes `:subject="message$", it will replace attribute **subject**'s value with the value of **message$** property on the corresponding **data** object. In your case, **message$** does not belongs **data** object so failed to bind. 
Please try following changes.

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';
const messageObservable = new Rx.Subject();
export default{
    data: function(){
       return {
           greeting: "My Name",
           message$: messageObservable
       }
    },
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the way the plugin for Vue-Rx wants you to do it but I can try and see if it works.